# iOS: In-App-Purchase fails for some users in production

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've recently released an iPad app which has a non-consumable "pro upgrade"-style In-App-Purchase.

It works for most users, and it worked when testing. However, I do get daily reports of the IAP crapping out for some customers of the app.

It is the worst kind of bug:

- For most people, it seems to work fine.
- For some people, it works after a reboot of the device or logging out from the App Store.
- For
  some other people, nothing seems to help and they can't make the
  purchase.

And I do not have any remote logging implemented...

This seems to happen across various locales / different iPad models / OS versions.

For those which can't make the purchase, usually an error pops up which says that their Apple ID password is incorrect, after confirming the purchase.

The purchase button in the app only appears after the IAP product was received from Apple's server successfully.

I am not sure how to track down what's going on there. I was initially thinking it's on Apple's side, but the number of people reporting it tells me it must be something with my app.

Any best practices on how to debug this?
thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Lots of purchases failing for people in production (from my Analytics data). It doesn't seem to be specific to any country, language, device, OS version, or app version. I also tried different store frameworks (Parse and RMStore), both with the same results. The error message is "Cannot connect to iTunes store".